# Pentaho Data Integration Multiway Merge Join

Tags: pentaho, pentaho-data-integration

I want to use the Multiway Merge Join step in Pentaho?  The documentation is woefully lacking, and it's not doing what I intuitively thought it would do.

I have the following tables defined in Oracle:

```
JOE1:
A   B   C
1   NY  3
2   NJ  1
3   NJ  3
4   CT  7

JOE2:
B   D
CT  Connecticut
NJ  New Jersey
NY  New York

JOE3:
C   E
1   one
3   three
7   seven
```

Here's the metadata from my Multiway Merge Join step in my .ktr:

```
Step name:  Multiway Merge Join

Input Table1:  JOE1    Join Keys: B,C
Input Table2:  JOE2    Join Keys: B
Input Table3:  JOE3    Join Keys: C
Join Type:  INNER
```

I would've expected my .ktr to produce something like this:

```
A   B   C   B_1 D           C_1 E
1   NY  3   NY  New York    3   three
2   NJ  1   NJ  New Jersey  1   one
3   NJ  3   NJ  New Jersey  3   three
4   CT  7   CT  Connecticut 7   seven
```

But, instead, I get the following error:

```
**2018/10/12 14:44:25 - Multiway Merge Join.0 - Unexpected conversion error while converting value [B String(2)] to an Integer
2018/10/12 14:44:25 - Multiway Merge Join.0 - 
2018/10/12 14:44:25 - Multiway Merge Join.0 - B String(2) : couldn't convert String to Integer
2018/10/12 14:44:25 - Multiway Merge Join.0 - 
2018/10/12 14:44:25 - Multiway Merge Join.0 - B String(2) : couldn't convert String to number : non-numeric character found at position 1 for value [CT]**
```

This is an indication that it's not joining on the field I defined to join on in the .ktr.

Unfortunately, my company's firewall prevents me from sending a link to any files or images.  I'm hoping I've provided enough information for someone to advise me if I've done something wrong or even if my behavioral expectations are accurate.

Answer (score 0):

The multi merge join is not like a SQL-join. It is a merge, looking like a SQL sorted union. It taking two flows (Joe1 and Joe2) and put the record one after the other taking the *lowest* record. In particular the flow metadata (column name, type and order) must be the same, something the PDI should have warned you (unless you pressed the Don't tell me anymore button previously).

You can use the `Join row (cartesian product)`. Don't worry it is **not** a cartesian product because you can specify that `JOE1.B = JOE2.B` (and many more). The PDI will remember you to sort the incoming flows before (unless you pressed the Don't tell me anymore button previously). Of course you have to make this twice: once to join Joe1 with Joe2, and once to join the resulting stream to Joe3.

In your case however, you are not after *joins* but after a *look up*. For each Joe1.B you are search for exactly one Joe2.B, and for each Joe1.C you are looking foe exactly one Joe3.C. Just like in the attached picture, on which the first lookup is open so that you can see the parameters. [Do not forget to specify the type of the returned column!]

Note that you can always put all this in the SQL: `SELECT * FROM joe1 JOIN joe2 ON joe2.B=joe1.B JOIN joe3 ON joe3.C=joe1.C`. But this will be harder to maintain, and if the query are complex (lots of join and many cross table relations), it may be slower that the PDI.

[image]

Comment: Thanks very much for this.  I ALMOSST figured this out on my own, so thanks for the confirmation, and for bridging the rest of my understanding!!

Comment: Then, please, validate the answer.

Answer (score 0):

It would appear that the join has to be done on the same field(s) for all input streams.  It doesn't have to have the same field name(s) but, conceptually, has to have the same data content.

Thanks to AlainD for the verification and the detailed explanation!!